# id on echo is found but not for other things

Tags: php, html, pdo

So when i do

```
<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>
```

i get a result : `1`

But when i use it for my query  i get the error

```
This discussion does not exists.
```

I copy pasted the code a bit because the rest of it is not needed in this question. 
This is my code :

```
if(isset($_GET['id']))
{
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    //We get the title and the narators of the discussion
    $req1 = $db->prepare('select title, user1, user2 from pm where id="'.$id.'" and id2="1"');
    $req1->execute();
    $dn1 = $req1->fetch();
    echo $dn1['title'];

    {
       echo '<div class="message">This discussion does not exists.</div>';
    }
}
```

Comment: can you test the query using PHPMyAdmin? `select title, user1, user2 from pm where id="1" and id2="1"`

Comment: Can you show you `connection code` or refer this http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php. Also check that you have data in your database. Use `if else` to show `title` or `no record found message`.

Comment: That last block runs regardless, did you forget to add a condition?

Comment: There is no point using prepare() if you don't bind parameters either by using bind() or by passing them to execute().

Comment: @RohanKumar i'm not using mysql1 :s

Comment: `$id = (int)$_GET['id'];` did u tried that?

Comment: Could u show the print_r for `$dn1` variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing it wrong way.

```
$sql = 'select title, user1, user2 from pm where id=? and id2=1';
$req = $db->prepare($sql);
$req->execute(array($_GET['id']));
$row = $req1->fetch();
if (!$row)
{
    echo '<div class="message">This discussion does not exists.</div>';
}
```

Also make sure you are connecting as described in the [PDO tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info)

Answer (score 0):

Make assure that you have proper records in your DB against mentioned $id.

Please use echo $dn1->title;

AND "This discussion does not exists."  code block COMES INSIDE YOUR IF BLOCK.

write else condition in a different block.

print your last query as a string and sort out the issue.

happy testing.